# Good source of country names in different languages? (for use in multilingual forms)

Tags: internationalization, translation, countries

I am building a multilingual web application with a possibility to change the interface language on the fly. This implies, among many other things, a country name selector on registration/profile forms should be translated too.

So I'm wondering if there is some kind of a centralized resource somewhere on the web for country names in all or many (or some) languages. I need only three of them, and I know most likely I'll end up translating the English names (can be found easily on the web) to the other two languages myself. Which is OK, unless my customers add more languages that I don't speak. And of course there should be some mapping between the names through, say, their 2-letter codes.

Comment: This question seems to be largely answered at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/download-list-of-the-name-of-every-country-in-western-languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://cldr.unicode.org/ - common standard multilanguage database include country list  and other localizable data.

Comment: Hi! It looks difficult to use.

Comment: You also yould use this files maybe: https://github.com/mledoze/countries/tree/master/dist